# Unexpected noise when using audiotrack + audiorecord class in android

Tags: android, audio-streaming

I am doing an Android IP phone application with android 2.1 version.
My application is to provide a simple ip phone function.My program consist of a listener thread which receive command and poll user to start the call.
The audiotrack class will receive audio data and playback
while it will record audio data with audiorecord and stream it out to the other side.

When there is only one user streaming to another, the sound quality is good.However, when the receiver side also start record and stream, both side ear weird sound and loud noise.But still both sides can hear what the others said.

Is it not suitable for using audiotrack and audiorecord class on the same side?I cannot figure out the problem. Can anyone suggest any solution?